# Problem creating energy material in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I'm trying to make an effect of pulsing electricity/energy in cycles but the tutorial I've been following was in blender render and used transparency options that aren't in the materials tab in cycles.  How can I make the material so that it has a harsh ripple-like outline?  Right now it looks more like a ghostly jelly :p

This is what I have so far:

[image]

But with the cube, I want to have this effect:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a link to the tutorial you mentioned?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnrsoSagIU8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference with your setup and that of the "Tutorial" is that the base material is not completely transparent.

If you mix the transparent with a translucent material, and then mix that with an emission shader using fresnel information, you can get something similar.

[image]

*Click on the image to enlarge*

Of course you can always make things more complicated and add another emission shader with a texture as volume:

[image]

Comment: Oh man that totally worked!  I used the first option with a mix shader of .999 and fresnel of 1.05 and it gave me exactly what I was looking for!  So thankful for this solution :)